# Как в R загрузить несколько txt файлов и сохранить данные в один файл?

Tags: r

Как на языке R осуществить загрузку нескольких `txt` файлов и сохранить данные в один файл?

Answer (score 0):

```
res <- unlist(lapply(list.files(indir, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE), readLines))
writeLines(res, outfile)
```

Или

```
for (f in list.files(indir, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE))
    cat(readLines(f), file = outfile, sep = "\r\n", append = TRUE)
```

Comment: а что значит indir? res <- unlist((lapply(list.files(indir, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE), readLines))
writeLines(res, outfile) как будто бы не законченный ++ выходятъ

Comment: `indir` перемення, содержащая путь к директории с файлами.